# Sed search conditions - one positive AND one negative but for exact string

Tags: sed

There is a text in a file:

```
1. # OPTIONS="blah --group http blah-blah-blah"
2. OPTIONS="--group http blah-blah-blah --group1 admins"
3. OPTIONS="--group http blah-blah-blah --group1 users2"
4. OPTIONS="--group http blah-blah-blah --group1 user"
5. OPTIONS=" blah-blah-blah --group bind"
6. OPTIONS="blah-blah-blah --group radius --group1 users"
7. OPTIONS "blah-blah-blah --group http --group1 users"
8. OPTIONS="blah-blah-blah --group1 users --group http"
```

I need to substitute `--group` from `http` to `radius` but at lines only, meeting the conditions:

1. the *line must begin with `OPTIONS=*` (in particular it is non commented line),
2. where `*--group1` is NOT `users*`,
3. of course if `*--group` is `http*`.

That is, there are 2 search conditions and 1 substitution condition.

I do the following with sed:

```sh
sed -i -r "/(^OPTIONS=.)(.*--group1 [^users].*)/ s/--group http/--group $radius/g" file
```

At the case the 2nd condition is negative for: either `u` or `s` or `e` or `r` or s`, but I need to get negative for the whole exact string` users`.

From below example, only lines 2, 3, 4 meet the conditions.
How is to reach so?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` has it's own language with it's own simple `if`s. Do not write one expression. Actually write the conditions:

```
sed '
# the line must begginning from OPTIONS= (in particular it is non commented line),
/^OPTIONS=/{
    # where --group1 is NOT users,
    /--group1 users/!{
        # of course if --group is http.
        /--group http/{
            s//--group radius/
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: `/--group1 users[" ]/` or `/--group1 users\b/`. Possibly worth doing for `http` too.

Comment: Thanks, KamilCuk and jhnc. I used additionally /--group1 users\b/. And what is necessary to change that only the last line from matching the rules would be changed, not all - only 4th line among 2, 3, 4 ?

Comment: @CpServiceSPb That's more difficult. How big is the file? How many lines match?

Comment: It's text config file. For my oppinion, lines will be not more than 10 - 20 lines, usually are 3-5.

Comment: `<file tac | sed -ne '/^OPTIONS=/{/--group1 users\b/!{ s/\(--group \)http\b/\1radius/;tf;}};p;d;:f;p;n;bf' | tac >tmp; mv tmp file`